# Delay on built in keyboard when USB-C charger is plugged in

Tags: usb, keyboard, power-management, usb-c

I have a Dell Precision 5510 laptop with Ubuntu 22.04. It's generally working fine.

What's strange is **when plugging in a USB-C charger, the built-in keyboard starts misbehaving, by randomly missing key presses** or small ~500ms delay on key presses.

When plugging in the charger, after about 7 seconds `journalctl` tells me:

```
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.HEC.CHRG], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)

No Local Variables are initialized for Method [PNOT]

No Arguments are initialized for method [PNOT]

ACPI Error: Aborting method \PNOT due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.AC._PSR due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
ACPI: \_SB_.AC__: Error reading AC Adapter state: AE_NOT_FOUND
dell_wmi: Unknown key with type 0x0012 and code 0x0000 pressed
```

- The rest of the computer works fine and at high performance both with and without charger plugged in.
- The charge icon lits up when plugging in the USB-C charger.
- I've used the USB-C port sucessfully for other things like displays.
- Charging with the normal DC-jack does not give same type of keyboard misbehavior.

The usb-c charger is from lenovo.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's just random thoughts, but **maybe** the charger, if it offers different voltage levels, tries to communicate with the device to choose the appropriate level. If the chip in the charger is not a widely used chip, it might be recognized as a USB-C keyboard in Ubuntu 22.04.

You can try running `dmesg --follow` on one terminal and `xev` or `showkey` on another, then plugging your cable back in to see if either of them responds to input from the USB-C cable.

If the charger cable is detachable, and you have another USB-C cable that has **no data lines, only power lines**, you can try charging the laptop with that cable and see if the problem persists.

Comment: dmesg shows same as journalctl, attached in original question. Neither xev nor showkey show any actions when charger get plugged in.